# Create a table with Count/High/Low from another table

Tags: mysql, count, max, create-table

I have a table with

City | State | Race | Value

Where there can be multiple records of same City/State/Race and different value.

I want to create a new table with a single record per City|State|Race

with

Count (# of records from original table with City/State/Race)
High (value from that City/State/Race count which has the highest value)
Low (value from that City/State/Race with the lowest value)

Ideally I could also have a Count # which would give the % of Count against all other City/State/Race combos.

Comment: What have you written so far?

Answer (score 0):

I would manually create a second table (let's say table2) with fields City, State, Race, Count, High and Low fields and then run the following query:

```
insert into table2 (city, state, race, count, high, low)
select distinct city, state, race, count(*), max(value), min(value)
from table1;
```

I can't test this right now so I'm not 100% sure if this will work, but will be very grateful if you can try this and give feedback.

Comment: Hi thanks that did not work for me I ended up with 5 of the same City/State/Race records with Count being the total # of records in the source table and max and min being the max min values in that table unrelated to the 5 records. I did group by instead i.e. removed distinct and then added 'Group by city, state, race, count(*), max(value), min(value) adter the from table1.